# Ansible fail task but continue running

Tags: ansible

I'm currently writing a bunch of checks for Ansible.

It involves contacting remote machines and performing a check.

Based on the result of this check, I make a decision whether it failed or not.

This is the important bit: the task itself never fails. It merely returns a message. I register the result and then analyze it. And based on that I decide if it's a failure or not.

The thing is, I want to add a flag that allows tests to keep running instead of failing.

So the code looks like this:

```
- name: Check fail.
  fail:
    msg: "Test failed"
  when: "failfast_flag and <the actual check>"
```

The problem there is, if I make failfast_flag `false`, it doesn't output red anymore.

I want it to continue with the next tests, in that case, but I also want it to color red, indicating it's an error/fail.

How do I accomplish this?

EDIT: Thanks for the suggestions, I'll give them a try in a bit.

Comment: Have you tried adding `ingore_erros: yes` to the task?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure i fully understood your question, but you could use a `- block` and `rescue` structure in order to treat the failures and continue the playbook in failure scenarios:

example:

```
- block:
    - name: Check fail.
      fail:
      msg: "Test failed"
      when: "failfast_flag and <the actual check>"
  rescue:
    - name: do somthing when the task above fails
      command: <do somthing>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a combination of @edrupado's answer and @Jack's comment.

The idea is to move the error up to the task where you register the value and use a rescue block to fail with an informative message, skipping the fail with a flag.

I have no idea what your actual task to collect data is. I used a dummy example cheking for the presence of a dir/file. You should be able to adapt to you actual scenario.

```
---
- name: Dummy POC just to test feasability
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

    - block:

        - name: Make sure /whatever dir exists
          stat:
            path: /whatever
          register: whatever
          failed_when: not whatever.stat.exists | bool

        - debug:
            msg: "/whatever exists: Good !"

      rescue:

        - fail:
            msg: /whatever dir must exist.
          ignore_errors: "{{ ignore_flag | default(false) | bool }}"

    - block:

        - name: Make sure /tmp dir exists
          stat:
            path: /tmp
          register: tmpdir
          failed_when: not tmpdir.stat.exists | bool

        - debug:
            msg: "/tmp exists: Good !"

      rescue:

        - fail:
            msg: /tmp dir must exist.
          ignore_errors: "{{ ignore_flag | default(false) | bool }}"
```

Which gives:

```
$ ansible-playbook /tmp/test.yml

PLAY [Dummy POC just to test feasability] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Make sure /whatever dir exists] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed_when_result": true, "stat": {"exists": false}}

TASK [fail] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "/whatever dir must exist."}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=1    ignored=0

$ ansible-playbook /tmp/test.yml -e ignore_flag=true

PLAY [Dummy POC just to test feasability] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Make sure /whatever dir exists] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed_when_result": true, "stat": {"exists": false}}

TASK [fail] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "/whatever dir must exist."}
...ignoring

TASK [Make sure /tmp dir exists] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "/tmp exists: Good !"
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=1    ignored=1
```